# How to redirect to other host using mod_rewrite in Apache

Tags: regex, apache, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need to create Rewrite Rule for mod_rewrite in Apache but it's really hard for me to understand this whole syntax.

I have links such as:

```
http://www.example.com/0001/images/image1.gif
```

and I need them to redirect it to completely other server like:

```
http://127.127.127.127/0001/images/image1.gif
```

Is this achievable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `example.com` enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://127.127.127.127%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```